# Why does this usort()-function fail on some versions of PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, usort

We wrote some code involving usort which works fine on our development systems (PHP 5.2.8), but are experiencing a problem on our live systems (PHP 5.2.0):

```
// Sort by distance
usort($locations, 'Interpolator::sortByDistance');
```

calls the method (within the same class Interpolator):

```
private static function sortByDistance($a, $b) {
    $return = 0;
    if($a['distance'] > $b['distance']) {
        $return = 1;
    } else if ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) {
        $return = -1;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

On our live systems, this returns a completely arbitrarily sorted array, the original order is disturbed, but still not sorted by distance.

I cannot find any reference to a PHP bug fixed between 5.2.0 and 5.2.8 relevant to this problem.

Where might this problem be coming from? Can I fix this short of writing a sorting function myself?

Comment: Does the string 'Interpolator::sortByDistance' work as a callback in all PHP versions?  I've always used the convention array ('Iterpolator', 'sortByDistance') for static method callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only think I can think of is that you should be using this:

```
usort($locations, array('Interpolator', 'sortByDistance'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but like chaos commented on my question, that's a 5.2.3-feature.

Comment: Nice.  Guess they broke the support somewhere along the road to 5.8.0.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the question comments.  5.8.0 doesn't exist - I guess you meant 5.2.0 on the server, so before 'Interpolator::sortByDistance' style was added.

Comment: @chaos: I just assumed 5.8.0 was a typo and he meant 5.2.0.  5.2.8 is the latest version of PHP.

Comment: Seems related to http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29049 but claims to have been fixed 5 years ago!

Comment: Guess I should've gone with my first thought, "uhh are you *sure* you're running 5.8.0?"